# Pourquoi ces 6 adjectifs de couleur s'accordent même s'ils référencent un nom?

Tags: adjectifs, accord, pluriel, genre

On sait que les adjectifs de couleur en un mot (« vert », « bleu », « blanc »...) s'accordent en genre et en nombre avec le nom s'y référant :

> Les chemises bleues
>   Les couettes vertes

Seulement, ce n'est pas le cas pour les couleurs se référant à un nom :

> Les pantalons orange
>   Les portes marron

Pourtant, les 6 adjectifs de couleur suivants s'accordent même s'ils référencent un nom (« rose », « fauve », « incarnat », « écarlate », « pourpre » et « mauve ») :

> Les fleurs roses
>   Les assiettes mauves

Pourquoi ces 6 derniers adjectifs de couleur font exception ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'explication est simple mais pas nécessairement logique. En fait, tu as la réponse écrite dans ta question. Les six exceptions sont des noms qui en sont venus à être considérés comme adjectifs (ce qui n'est pas le cas de marron ou orange). C'est ce qu'affirme l'[Office québecois](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1721) de la langue française. L'[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#24_strong-em-couleur-accord-de-l-adjectif-et-du-nom-em-strong) dit plutôt que seulement quatre sont d'abord des noms donc constituent des exceptions:

> On recense traditionnellement quatre exceptions à cette règle : rose, mauve, pourpre et écarlate, qui sont variables. Fauve et incarnat, étant d’abord des adjectifs, sont naturellement variables.

**Edit**
L'OQLF a ajouté *vermeil* à la liste.

Comment: Cela voudrait dire que _orange_ et _marron_ étaient des adjectifs avant d'être des noms ?

Comment: @Zistoloen Exactement le contraire. Orange et marron était des noms d'abord (et ne s'accordent donc pas). Ils sont toujours considérés comme des noms contrairement à rose ou mauve qui sont devenus des adjetifs à part entière.

Comment: @Zistoloen : Quels sont les 4 exceptions qui ne sont que des noms et non pas des adjectifs ? Je ne les perçois pas dans le lien ci-devant ?

Comment: Selon l'Académie française: rose, mauve, pourpre et écarlate. L'OQLF affirme qu'ils sont désormais des adjectifs.

Answer (score -1):

"*Orange*" et "*marron*" ont encore le caractère d'un nom. On peut expliquer "*des pantalons de couleur d'une orange*". Bien sûr on omet "*de couleur d'une*".
De même pour "*marron*".

Comment: Ces deux exemples semblent étranges. Un des tests classiques pour distinguer un adjectif d'un nom consiste à le modifier par *très*. Les noms, comme *acajou* ou *vermeil*, ne sont pas compatible avec *très* mais ça ne semble pas être le cas pour *orange* ou *marron*...