# L'apport de la « carte vermeil » invariable du rail : « génération vermeil », type d'âge etc. ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, lexique, france, transports

Le vermeil ou la couleur vermeille est un « rouge éclatant, légèrement plus foncé que l'incarnat et tirant sur le rouge cerise » ou, par analogie avec l'« [a]rgent (autrefois cuivre), recouvert d'une dorure tirant sur le rouge », quelque chose « [q]ui a l'éclat ou la couleur du vermeil; qui est d'un ton d'or chaud, orangé ou jaune doré » (TLFi).

---

Certains trouvent « fâcheuse » l'exception (à l'[exception](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/7537/3177)...) à l'accord des adjectifs de couleurs simples que constitue la *carte vermeil* (« [permettant] aux voyageurs à partir de 60 ans de bénéficier de réductions sur les tarifs des transports de la S.N.C.F. », [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vermeil/81560/locution)), dont on dit au surcroît qu'elle mène à des « emplois métonymiques incompréhensibles hors de France » comme *vacances vermeil*, *génération vermeil*, et l'ultime substantivation avec ellipse *samedi « vermeils »* soit le samedi *pour les retraités*, où l'invariabilité cède finalement sa place ; on réfère à la médaille en vermeil octroyée par la *Société nationale des chemins de fer français* (LBU14 § 555 R1), ou *médaille de vermeil* :

> Le chef de la circonscription de Nancy-ouest, (...) et les chefs de
>   gare concernés, ont remis des médailles de vermeil, pour 35 ans de
>   service et d'argent, pour 25 ans, à 23 agents.
>
> [*L'Est Républicain*, 18 nov. 1993, p. 611, col. 1 ds. TLFi à
>   [*vermeil*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vermeil) ]

Par ailleurs on a évidemment plusieurs âges ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A2ge), [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A2ge/1613/locution)), dont le *deuxième âge*, c'est-à-dire le *nourrisson dès six mois*, puis le *troisième âge*, « période de la vie où cessent les activités professionnelles ; la vieillesse » (Larousse) ; on a les aînés et la [*personne âgée*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17049404) ; au Québec on déjà employé [*(de) l'âge d'or*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9seau_FADOQ) pour désigner un âge mûr du type du troisième, semble-t-il.

---

- Qu'est-ce qu'une *génération vermeil* (le *Monde*, sélection
  hebdomadaire, 18 janvier 1996, p. 1) ?
- *Vermeil* en apport au nom a-t-il vocation en langue courante à supplanter *du troisième âge* ou à le compléter, le préciser ; est-il en voie d'être lexicalisé avec un autre support que *carte* dans un sens étendu ?
- En quoi *vermeil* diffère-t-il du troisième âge, réfère-t-il exclusivement au niveau d'activité professionnelle ou à un âge ou aux deux ; *âge vermeil* serait-il redondant ou incohérent ?
- Une curiosité : la carte Senior+ de la S.N.C.F. est-elle d'une
  couleur particulière (rouge, argent etc.) ; est-elle même encore physiquement une carte ?

Comment: La "Carte Senior" a le format et la couleur d'un billet de train grandes lignes. J'ai trouvé [ça sur google images](http://bit.ly/2kTjXe8). (C'est pas la mienne mais je certifie qu'elles sont comme ça actuellement). L'ancêtre de la Carte Senior - la [Carte Vermeil](http://bit.ly/2kTnicO) - était un vraie carte et bordée de "rouge".

Comment: Pa suffisant pour une réponse mais,  Carte Vermeil (plus employé depuis que cette carte a été remplacée par la Carte Senior - je ne sais  plus quand mais ce n'est pas récent) avait été pris par analogie à la Médaille vermeil  du travail (peut être décernée après 30 ans de service), confirmé par Dictionnaire culturel en langue française). Je pense donc qu'il faille rapprocher l'association vermeil/personnes au-delà d'un certain âge à l'ancienneté dans l'emploi pour avoir la médaille vermeil du travail. Ça ne dit pas pourquoi le choix de vermeil pour la médaille (qui n'est pas vermeil).

Comment: Et bien sûr la médaille vermeil à cause des noces de vermeil (45 ans de mariage).

Comment: Cette archive non officielle de l'émission « Parler au quotidien » de RFI, à priori datant de 1999, qui traite des différents usages de vermeil http://www.chilton.com/paq/archive/PAQ-99-099.html mérite d'être lue.

Comment: @jlliagre Intéressant, un terme de l'article est commun avec un terme dans la réponse. Il est possible d'aller brièvement plus avant dans cette direction. Merci !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il me semble qu'il y a dans la question confusion entre l'emploi de vermeil en tant que couleur (adjectif)  ou comme métal (nom).

Le vermeil est un [métal précieux](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermeil) constitué d'argent plaqué d'or, et si la quantité d'or varie selon les pays, l'or utilisé actuellement est de couleur jaune ou gris. En tant que valeur marchande il se situe après l'argent et avant l'or. L'appellation « vermeil » pour ce métal peut remonter au temps où le vermeil pouvait être un plaquage d'or sur du cuivre (et non pas sur de l'argent comme actuellement), et si la couche d'or était fine le résultat final pouvait avoir une teinte légèrement rougeâtre à cause du cuivre qui transparaissait. L'or n'a de teinte rouge que quand il est très pur, et donc cet or coûte très cher. Mais je n'ai rien trouvé pour étayer cette supposition.

En effet, le mot « vermeil » est un terme littéraire et générique désignant diverses nuances de rouges orangés. Le terme ne se trouve pas en tant que terme scientifique dans les nuanciers où la seule occurrence rappelant le terme est celle de [vermillon](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermillon_(couleur)). Dans la littérature du moyen-âge la couleur vermeil était souvent [associée au sang](http://books.openedition.org/pup/3663?lang=fr#tocfrom1n3).

Ce classement du vermeil dans les métaux précieux a conduit le terme a être adopté pour symboliser diverses récompenses (après l'or et avant l'argent) sportives ([en ski](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fl%C3%A8che_(niveau)) par exemple),  ou dans la vie civile où il symbolise une étape, comme les noces de vermeil pour 45 ans de mariage ou un grade comme les diverses [médailles vermeil](https://www.monnaiedeparis.fr/fr/search-mixed?query=vermeil) qui sont en vermeil mais qui ne sont pas de couleur vermeil.

On peut légitimement penser que l'association du terme « vermeil » aux personnes d'un certain âge est pensé comme une « récompense » pour avoir franchi un certain nombre d'étapes dans la vie. Par exemple, quand au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle la SNCF a créé une Carte Vermeil, nom commercial de la carte de réduction pour les personnes de plus de 60 ans, ils ont préféré adopter ce terme pour éviter de parler de « Carte personnes âgées » ou de « Carte Vieillesse » qui auraient probablement été perçu de façon négative.
À noter que dans « Carte Vermeil », comme dans « [Médaille Vermeil du travail](https://www.monnaiedeparis.fr/fr/professionnels/la-medaille-d-honneur-du-travail) », le terme est un substantif désignant un grade, ou le métal, et pas un adjectif de couleur. La médaille est en vermeil ; dans la cas de la carte SNCF il s'agit d'un nom qui a été choisi par analogie avec les diverses récompenses sportives ou au mérite de ce nom, on pourrait dire que c'est un nom propre et officiellement on parle de « Carte Vermeil » avec des majuscules. En 1990 la Carte Vermeil a été remplacée par la Carte Senior (devenue Senior + en 2012) et ce n'est que très récemment que la SNCF [a déposé le terme](http://www.deplacementspros.com/Carte-Vermeil-le-retour_a37366.html) auprès de l'INPI.

Il suffit d'une recherche google pour voir que le terme de « [génération vermeil](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ration%20vermeil%20&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) » (évoqué dans la question) pour désigner la tranche d'âge des plus de 60 ans est très peu employé, de même pour « [âge vermeil](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=%C3%A2ge%20vermeil&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) », cet emploi est très daté et je doute que les jeunes générations de Français le comprennent. Le terme reçu pour désigner cette tranche d'âge est « senior », il est d'ailleurs intéressant de voir que le terme de « [senior](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senior) », (comme avant celui de « vermeil ») est dépendant du contexte social dans lequel il est employé, on est un senior dans son entreprise avant de l'être pour la SNCF ou pour la sécurité sociale.

> Certains trouvent « fâcheuse » l'exception à l'accord des adjectifs de couleurs simples que constitue la carte vermeil

Même si la carte avait été de couleur vermeil et qu'on ne veuille pas adhérer à mon interprétation sur l'emploi ici du substantif, il resterait que vermeil est un nom employé comme adjectif et donc la règle est : « Le nom employé pour désigner une couleur peut être simple ou composé ; dans les deux cas, il reste invariable parce qu'il est complément du mot « couleur » sous-entendu ou qu'il y a une comparaison implicite. » [Grevisse, §381b, 10<sup>e</sup> édition],  *vermeil* ne fait pas partie des exceptions à la règle que sont *écarlate, mauve, pourpre* et *rose*, notées dans son *nota bene*. Voir aussi [cet article](http://zendictee.fr/Billet/detail/27) sur l'accord des adjectifs de couleur qui me semble bien fait.

Comment: @のｂるしｔｙぱんｋｙ Les parties du discours/Accord de l'adjectif qualificatif/Mots désignant une couleur.

Comment: ref. l'intitulé du §381b ds. 10 : Les parties du discours/Accord de l'adjectif qualificatif/Mots désignant une couleur. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

- Je ne suis pas complètement sûr, mais je dirais qu'une *génération vermeil* est la génération qui satisfait les critères pour obtenir la carte vermeil - sans doute des personnes âgées en général.
- *Génération vermeil* n'apparaît pas encore dans les statistiques de ngrams - qui bien sûr *suit* les phénomènes linguistiques plus qu'il ne les précède:

[image]

Voici également les 10 expressions les plus fréquentes contenant le mot *vermeil*, ou tout au moins, celles que ngrams connaît à ce jour (j'ai réduit la période de recherche à 1980-présent puisqu'il s'agit d'une question sur le présent plutôt qu'historique - cela permet de mieux voir les expressions couramment utilisées):

[image]

Toujours d'après ngrams, le mot *senior* est maintenant plus fréquent que *troisième âge*, dont les beaux jours étaient plutôt dans les années 80:

[image]

mais il faudrait aussi voir s'il y a d'autres expressions, hormis *vermeil*. On me dit que *senior* est bien le terme préféré de nos jours. A vérifier.

- Je pense que *vermeil* est vague, je ne saurais pas dire quelles différences il pourrait y avoir avec *troisième âge* - c'est simplement un euphémisme dérivé de la couleur de ladite carte.
- Je ne satisfais pas aux conditions pour avoir droit à une telle carte, donc cette information n'est pas de première main, mais d'après ce que je vois sur Google Images, elle n'est pas *vermeil* :-)

Comment: J'avais essayé _NOUN_vermeil, et toutes les combinaisons de * et autres que j'ai pu imaginer, sans succès. Avez-vous un lien sur la bonne recherche ngrams? Je modifierais ma réponse en fonction. Senior est peut-être un mot d'emprunt, mais on me dit que c'est bien le terme le plus usité couramment.

Comment: Merci! J'avais choisi le corpus "French (2009)", qui ne retournait aucun résultat!!!